Python - Solutions to iterating over a dynamic variable name
The layout of my dialog box
the error
I am attempting to create an application where I dynamically generate number of checkboxes (the number of checkboxes depends on the number of unique items in a text file). After which the user is required to type in a value. If the value entered is equal to the name assigned to one of the checkboxes, then the checkbox will be checked off.
The GUI interface I have available to me creates dialog boxes and supports event handling. But the problem is that the only way I can check off a checkbox is through code similar to this: dialog.fixtureDictionary['fixtureName_0'].value = True
where "dialog" is the dialog window, "fixtureDictionary['fixtureName_0']" is the name of one of the checkboxes, and 'value=True' allows me to check off a checkbox.
When I run this code, my dialog event handler does not understand that "fixtureDictionary['fixtureName_0']" must actually correspond to the value of 'T30' (as an example). Instead, it's explicitly looking for the variable named 'fixtureDictionary'.
I am a bit new to Python, and am completely perplexed. I have been reading that it is generally bad practice to have dynamically named variables, but unfortunately every checkbox in my script is required to have a unique name.
Is there anyway to pass the dialog."something".value a dynamic name?
Main Code -
def verifyPartAndVMR(partInformation):

fixtureDictionary = {}
fixturePieceNo = 0

fixtureFile = open(str(fixtureFileDirectory) + '/FixtureList_' + partInformation['partNumber'] + '.txt', "r")
for aPiece in fixtureFile:
    fixtureDictionary['fixtureName_' + str(fixturePieceNo)] = aPiece.strip()
    fixturePieceNo += 1     
fixtureFile.close()

dialog=gom.script.sys.create_user_defined_dialog (content = buildDialog(fixtureDictionary))
    
    def dialog_event_handler(widget):
    
        while validScan(dialog.input_scanner.value):
            if dialog.input_scanner.value in fixtureDictionary.values():
                dialog.fixtureDictionary['fixtureName_0'].value = True
              
dialog.handler = dialog_event_handler
gom.script.sys.show_user_defined_dialog (dialog=dialog)

return 1    


def buildDialog(fixtureDictionary):

fixturePieceNo = 0

dialog = createBlankForm(500, 500, 10, 10)
dialog += addContinuousText(0,0,'<html><p align=\"center\"><span style=\"font-size:12pt; color:#000000;\">Example Text</span></p><p align=\"center\" style=\"-qt-paragraph-type:empty;       font-weight:600; color:#ff0000;\"><br/></p><p align=\"center\"><span style=\"font-size:20pt; font-weight:600; color:#ff0000;\">ABC123</span></p></html>')
dialog += addInputField(0,1, 'input_scanner')
dialog += addVerticalSpacer(1,2,1)

for eachPiece in fixtureDictionary:
    dialog += addCheckBox(0, 3 + fixturePieceNo, fixturePieceNo, fixtureDictionary['fixtureName_' + str(fixturePieceNo)])
    fixturePieceNo += 1
    
dialog += addVerticalSpacer(1,8,2)
dialog += addButton(0,9, 1, '', 'ok')
dialog += addButton(1,9, 2, '', 'cancel')

return dialog + '</content></dialog>'


def createBlankForm(width, height, numRows, numCols):

blankForm='<dialog>' \
'<title>Test Dialog</title>' \
'<style></style>' \
'<control id="Empty"/>' \
'<position></position>' \
'<embedding></embedding>' \
'<sizemode></sizemode>' \
'<size width="' + str(width) + '" height="' + str(height) + '"/>' \
'<content columns="' + str(numCols) + '" rows="' + str(numRows) + '">'

return blankForm


def addCheckBox(colPosition, rowPosition, instance, checkBoxName):

checkBox =  '<widget type="input::checkbox" rowspan="1" columnspan="1" row="' + str(rowPosition) + '"column="' + str(colPosition) + '">' \
            '   <name>' + checkBoxName + '</name>' \
            '   <tooltip></tooltip>' \
            '   <value>false</value>' \
            '   <title>' + checkBoxName + '</title>' \
            '</widget>'  
            
return checkBox


Can you share some example code?  The solution to this problem is to use a dictionary, which it sounds like you're already doing; the problem might be that in your event handler function you're not accessing the dictionary correctly.

@Samwise Thank you for your reply. I have included screenshots of the associated code.
